# omitting the pronoun "I"

Tags: pronouns

I want to know about the grammar of omitting pronouns. I've searched for it some times but I didn't find a proper answer.

Actually I want to write in my profile about my education, I want to write "I major in Physics and minor in Biology" but I don't want to use the pronoun "I". Is it grammatically correct to just write "Major in Physics, Minor in Biology"? and whether it is not, how should I express it?

Comment: it is grammatical but very informal. That's beside the point, however. The point is, omitting the pronoun *I* on a resume that is *all about you* is a rather strange thing to try and accomplish. Do you also avoid the word "car" when talking about cars? Do you also avoid the word "spaghetti" when ordering spaghetti? Why are you ashamed to admit that you, yes you, and not me and not that guy over there, that *you* have a major in physics? I'd wear such an accolade with pride.

Comment: In this particular example it looks like you are making listings if you omit "I", where "major" and "minor" are used as nouns. Other than that, since English is not a null-subject language such as Italian, you are not supposed to drop the pronouns. Even though heard often in spoken language, it is generally not accepted in written language.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Your comment here is correct - that it's grammatical. But unfortunately you've linked it to a question which basically says it isn't. And then that question is linked to a page where the top-voted and accepted answer categorically states that it is not grammatical. This can only be bad for this site. Dreadful outcome. Can we do something about this?

Comment: @JJMDriessen you mean I'm doing right in this especial case? and also I see it vital to add  that "major in" and "minor in" are both phrasal verbs here and I don't use the words "major" and "minor" as a noun.

Comment: @F.K In that case I would suggest adding "I".